# how to display image randomly inside for loop in php

Tags: php, html, image, for-loop, random

i have a simple webpage where i am trying to echo multiple images, my code is like below

```html
<?php for($l=1;$l<=45;$l++){?>

<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(l<?=$l?>.jpg);"></div>

<?php } ?>
```

so here the images are displayed fine in an order from 1 to 45, but what i want is images to display randomly everytime the page is loaded, can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this, thanks in advance

Comment: Create an array with the numbers from 1 to 45 (`range`), shuffle it, and then iterate over it with a `foreach` loop to create your divs.

Comment: @CBroe i tried that but its not working, https://onlinephp.io/c/0f632

Comment: Create the array _outside_ of the `for`/`foreach` loop using [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), _then_ shuffle it, _then_ iterate over the array

Comment: Shuffling and then looping over an array, that you put only one single element into to begin with, doesn't make much sense. And neither does nesting two loops here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, just create an array and shuffle it.

```
$images = [];
for ($l = 1; $l <= 45; $l++) {
    $images[] = "<div class='thumb' style='background-image: url(l{$l}.jpg);'></div>";
}
shuffle($images);
echo implode("\n", $images);
```